# how to stick an object to another object that has a wave modifier?

Tags: modifiers, edit-mode

I want to get the black strip to follow the wave motion of the white plane above it

[image]

i tried simply linking the modifiers of the black strip to the plane, but this was the result:
[image]

Here is the modifiers i am using on the plane:
[image]

Any solutions to this?

Comment: Does the black plane have enough geometry to deform along the waves ?

Comment: yup, tried with many subdivisions and the same "thickening" effect occurs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From your second screen it seems like wrong order of modifiers ... Solidify-Wave-Subdiv ... the order on the third one is correct (Subdiv-Wave-Solidify).

Are you sure both objects use this order?

---

Few Loop Cuts <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

[image]

[image]

Same modifiers

[image]

---

Another way ... use the *Wave* modifier only for *Plane* and for *Strip* object add **Surface Deform** modifier with *Plane* as target. Be sure before **Bind** disable *Wave* modifier and enable back after binding.

[image]

[image]